# Lots of requests to S3 from EC2 (Elastic Beanstalk Java Servlet) for no reason

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set up a Beanstalk environement with a micro EC2 Instance running a small Java servlet. The Servlet uses a couple of files on S3 for its operations but that are only a couple of requests in total each day.
For some reason under Account Activity there are over 40,000 requests listed (put,copy,post,list) and I have no idea where they are comming from (apart from a few when I upload the Servlet via Eclipse Plugin).
Where the hell are all these requests are coming from???

Comment: I know that is an old question, but I have the same problem, have you understand the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk stores a bunch of stuff on S3, under the hood. Please have a look [here](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/#store-in-s3). That might (and probably is) your case.